# C++. Как правильно конвертировать std::string (с массивом байт) в const std::char*

Tags: c++, строки

Я использую библиотеку CryptoPP для AES и RSA шифрования. И у меня возникает проблема при преобразовании `std::string` в `const std::char*`. На сколько я понимаю (по скриншотам ниже), проблема заключается в том, что функция `.c_str()` обрезает строку в месте где встречается *\0* или подобный символ.

Это функция шифрования:

```
string RSACryptography::Encrypt(string text) {
    string cipher_text;
    CryptoPP::StringSource(text, true, new CryptoPP::PK_EncryptorFilter(this->rng, this->publicKey, new CryptoPP::StringSink(cipher_text)));
    return cipher_text;
}
```

Здесь я вызываю эту функцию:

```
int main() {
    RSACryptography* CryptoRSA = new RSACryptography();
    string cipher_text = CryptoRSA->Encrypt("hellO");

    cout << "cipher text (string):\n" << cipher_text << "\n\n\n\n";
    
    cout << "cipher text (string.c_str()):\n" << cipher_text.c_str() << endl;
}
```

CryptoPP шифрует текст и пишет его в строку. При обычном выводе строки, и дальнейшей передаче в функцию дешифрования всё работает отлично. Однако при попытке перевести `std::string` в `const std::char*` (чем по сути string и является) возникает вот такая проблема:

[image: скриншот консоли вывода]

**НО!** В то же время, вероятность того, что функция `.c_str()` обрежет строку, около 80%. То есть бывают случаи когда правильно возвращается вся строка (в последующем для функции const_cast).
Прошу, подскажите варианты того, как правильно конвертировать такую строку в `const std::char*`.

P.S. Конвертировать `std::string` в `const std::char*` мне нужно для того, что бы я мог передать такую строку в Python. А для этого существует только 2 варианта типов: `const std::char*` или `const std::wchar_t*`

P.S.S. Когда я дешифрую полученную строку, всё прекрасно работает. 10 раз запустил, 10 раз сработало.
Тогда я конвертирую шифрованную строку в `const std::char*` и передаю её в функцию дешифрования. 10 раз запустил, 3 раза сработало(7 раз вылетело в ошибку) :(

```
int main() {
    RSACryptography* RSACrypt = new RSACryptography();
    string cipher_text = RSACrypt->Encrypt("hellO");

    cout << "cipher text (string):\n" << cipher_text << "\n\n\n\n";
    
    const char* cipher_text_char = const_cast<char*>(cipher_text.c_str());

    cout << RSACrypt->Decipher(cipher_text_char);
}
```

Comment: `c_str()` никаих модификаций со строкой не производит. `'\0'` является признаком завершения c-style строки, и соответствующая перегрузка оператора << дальше не печатает. Не стоит использовать печать для отладки. Массивы байт лучше хранить в `std::vector`.

Comment: `c_str()` ничего не обрезает, она честно возвращает указатель на массив `char`'ов, составляющих содержимое `std::string`. Нулевой символ в данном массиве интерпретируется как конец строки. Обычно нулевой символ всего один — последний элемент массива, но после шифрования он может оказаться где угодно. Если Python-функция определяет размер массива по нулевому символу, а массив может содержать нулевой символ где-нибудь в середине, то определить где же заканчивается массив символов не получится.

Comment: Смотри. Эту строку я засовываю в функцию дешифрования. 10 раз запустил, всё прекрасно работает. Тогда я преобразовываю ```std::string``` в ```const std::char*``` и кидаю эту строку в дешифрование:

const char* cipher_text_char = const_cast<char*>(cipher_text.c_str());

cout << RSACrypt->Decipher(cipher_text_char);

10 раз запустил, 3 раза сработало, понимаешь?
Один и тот же код или выполняется, или вылетает с ошибкой :(

Comment: Каким образом дешифровальщик должен узнать размер входных данных, получая на вход только указатель? Вы что-то делаете не правильно. Либо зашифрованная "строка" не должна содержать нулевые символы в середине, и тогда можно передавать `const char*` дешифровщику, либо дешифровщику также необходимо передавать размер зашифрованных данных.

Comment: `На сколько я понимаю (по скриншотам ниже), проблема заключается в том, что функция .c_str() обрезает строку в месте где встречается \0 или подобный символ` — нет, `c_str` ничего не обрезает. Просто функции, которые работают с C-style строками определяют размер строки по нулевому символу. Наткнулись на нулевой символ — строка закончилась.

Comment: *10 раз запустил, 3 раза сработало, понимаешь?* - ищите ошибку при работе с памятью. Где-то что-то у вас не так... Да, вместо этих `const_cast<char*>(cipher_text.c_str())` не проще использовать `cipher_text.data()`?

Comment: @wololo функция дешифрования на вход принимает зашифрованную строку, ```std::string```. То есть в функцию я могу передать как ```const std::char*```, так и ```std::string``` (конструктор сам преобразует ```const std::char*``` в ```std::string```). Я могу сделать код без функций и ООП, просто последовательное шифрование и дешифрование, но при преобразовании ```std::string``` в ```const std::char*```, и потом обратно в string(для того что бы отдать её CryptoPP), я всё равно получу ошибку.

Comment: @Harry тоже самое :(

Comment: `конструктор сам преобразует const std::char* в std::string` вот.... А как по вашему конструктор определяет, где конец строки? **По нулевому символу**

Comment: @wololo, да, я вас понял, но как мне убрать нулевые сивмолы в середине строки? Они играют важную роль для расшифрования )

Comment: Передавайте вместе с указателем размер массива? Например, конструктор `std::string` вторым аргументом может принять размер строки, и тогда на нулевом символе свою работу он не остановит. [Пример](https://ideone.com/22pry0).

Comment: Я не к тому, что `.data()` вместо `.c_str()` спасет, а к тому, что `.data()` возвращает, начиная с С++17, `char*`, так что приведение `const_char` не нужно. А ошибку ищите где-то в другом месте...

Comment: Покажите, как выглядит `RSACrypt->Decipher();` - как вы пишете - "при дальнейшей передаче в функцию дешифрования всё работает отлично" - но в эту функцию строку `string` вы передать не можете, нет? Так куда вы ее передаете?

Comment: @Harry, 
```string RSACryptography::Decipher(string text) {
 string decipher_text;
 CryptoPP::StringSource(text, true, new CryptoPP::PK_DecryptorFilter(this->rng, this->privateKey, new CryptoPP::StringSink(decipher_text)));
 return decipher_text;
}
```

Comment: Стоп-стоп! Вы что, вместо `string` просто берете и передаете указатель? Который преобразуется в `string`? Ну вот и ответ...

Comment: @Harry, @wololo именно, но дело не в этом. Я проверил, я получил зашифрованную строку, и посмотрел её размер. Всегда 256. Дальше преобразовал в ```const std::char*``` с помощью функции .data() или const_cast<char*>() (и так и так попробовал) и, когда смотрю размер получившейся строки, он отличается от 256-ти. Размер всегда рандомный, и только иногда соотвествует размеру зашифрованной строки

Comment: ```
        string cipher_text = RSACrypt->Encrypt("hellO");

 const char* x = cipher_text.data();
 
 cout << "cipher text (string):\n" << cipher_text << "\n\n\n\n"
  << "cipher test chars:\n" << x << "\n\n\n\n";


 cout << cipher_text.length() << endl;
        cout << strlen(x) << endl;
```

Comment: `когда смотрю размер получившейся строки, он отличается от 256-ти` потому что 256-элементный массив содержит где-то в середине нулевой символ. Я вам уже писал раньше, что функции, работающие с указателем `char*` определяют конец строки **по нулевому символу**. Конструктор `std::string`, принимающий только указатель, поступает аналогично. Наткнулся на нулевой символ? Всё. Конец строки. Какие там дальше идут символы его не волнует.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема, как я понимаю, в том, что

```
string RSACryptography::Decipher(string text)
```

Теперь смотрите - если вы передаете `string` - она идет со всеми нулевыми символами, все OK.

Но когда вы передаете аргументом `char*`, то сначала вызывается конструктор строки `string` для ее получения из `char*` - а этот конструктор, видя нулевой символ, считает это окончанием строки!

Вот тут обрезание и происходит...

См. [тут](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) описание пятого конструктора - он полагает, что ему передается строка с завершающим нулевым символом.

Разжевываю.

Пусть после шифрования строка `string cifer` состоит из каких-то байт, типа

```
05 3A 18 00 24 38 63
```

Если мы передает ее как строку для дешифровки - передаются все 7 байт. Но если мы передаем указатель на этот массив - то, **поскольку функция принимает `string`, а не `char*`, сначала выполняется создание строки из этой последовательности символов**. Конструктор `string` создан так, что если он получает указатель - то считает, что это указатель на строку с завершающим нулевым символом. Он создает новую строк `string` содержимое которой теперь

```
05 3A 18
```

Все! Потому что дальше - нулевой символ, строка считается завершенной - ну вот так написан конструктор!

Вот и несоответствие размеру, и обрезка по нулевому символу. Так понятно?

Comment: Попытался разжевать - см. исправленный ответ.

Comment: Да, спасибо, это я понял, и согласен. Но дело тут не в том, что функция преобразовывает std::char* в std::string. Проблема ещё на этапе функции .c_str().
Смотри. Я получил зашифрованную строку, и другой строке приравнял значение <шифрованная строка>.c_str(). Во-первых я вывел обе строки, и в большинстве случаев они отличаются друг от друга. "Может это перегрузка cout останавливает вывод строки на символе '\0', но на самом деле строки равны". И тогда я вывел их размер, и, к моему не удивлению я получил разные размер. .c_str() обрезает строку на символе '\0' (или я просто не так выражаюсь)

Comment: И потому, прошу, подскажи, как мне перевести строку со всеми символами в const std::char*. Я мог бы кастылять: шифровать строку, а после проверять, есть ли в теле строки символ '\0' и если есть, шифровать строку ещё раз. И отдавать в Python только нормальную, но это сильно ударит по производительности, и в принцепе кастылять я не хочу. :(((

Comment: Если вы потом хотите неявно преобразовывать ее назад в `string` - **НИКАК**. Проблема не в преобразовании `string -> const char*`, а в `const char* -> string`!